# Uploading csv file using filters

Tags: mysql, file-upload, csv

Am trying to upload CSV data to MYSQL table using the below query.It's running successfully. The CSV file having 20 million data. But still now I have a problem to upload the data.

My CSV file structure like this :

```
Name phone_no     DND
xxx  99934034343  A
xxx  99934034345  D
xxx  99934034346  A
xxx  99934034347  D
```

I want to insert the active no "A" only using the below command.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/root/782012_23.csv'
INTO TABLE tbl_dndno
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Expected record like this

```
Name phone_no     DND
 xxx  99934034343  A
 xxx  99934034346  A
```

Comment: what is your problem? what error do arise?

Comment: I can't able to upload "A" records.

Comment: why? what do you expect, what happens, which error do you see?

Comment: I want to store active phone numbers only. That means i want to insert phone no filter by DND column "A".

Comment: sorry, you are still not answering my questions: why does it not work? What is in your table after having run your command? Do you see errors?

Comment: I already told you.It's working fine. But am not able to store with filter option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your command is working fine but filling your table with 4 rows instead of the expected 2.

[LOAD DATA IN FILE documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/load-data.html) seem not to support what you are asking for, it can only exclude line by number, so if you have a way to know the line numbers while creating this csv file you could use this feature. Otherwise there are 2 workarounds:

You can filter your file before loading it (outside of mysql) with (on Linux)

```
grep "D$" /root/782012_23.csv > filteredfile; LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'filteredfile' ...
```

or filter after the loading via SQL:

```
your_command;mysql -u user -ppassword "DELETE FROM yourtable WHERE DND = 'A'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I think you put the down vote to me.I can't able to ask questions.Thank you so much..

Comment: no i didnt downvote the question otherwise i wouldnt have bothered to answer, but you must realize that you said nowhere that your loading was working but loading 4 lines instead of the 2 expected (read your question again), that would have helped a lot us then you and prevented a lot of downvotes :)